# Is buffer_size = file size useful for Rails send_file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

If the file sent with [send_file](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000044) is similar in size to the default buffer size (4096 bytes), *does it always make sense to use `stream: false`?* For example, are there proxies or browsers that break badly if the buffer size is non-standard?

Related:

1. Does the buffer size refer to the *file* or the *HTTP packet*?
2. Can you recommend a Firefox extension to inspect HTTP packets at this level?

Comment: rails buffer changes would affect rails->webserver communications. everything would still be mediated by the webserver before hitting the wire and going to the client.

Comment: @MarcB: What do you mean? Will the HTTP package size not be affected by the buffer size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#l_M000044_source), rails basically does

```
File.open(path, 'rb') do |file|
  while buf = file.read(len)
    output.write(buf)
  end
end
```

And the `buffer_size` option controls the value of `len`. Very small values of `len` are inefficient in terms of IO activity, very large values are wasteful of memory. How this then gets broken up into tcp packets is not under your control. If you were to change the value, increasing it to the size of the file would just be wasteful - I don't think you'd need anything more than a few hundred k - 128k or 256k would be ample. Optimal buffer sizes will be operating system / hardware dependant.